# java program input:-My input is:- googshaopobuieoele and output which I want is 7 ?

Tags: java

java program 
input:-My input is:- googshaopobuieoele and
 output which I want is  7 ?

**Note:- whatever my input I want to count only consonent not vowels.**

```
`   int j;  
    int Count=0;
    String scc="googshaopobuieoele";
    String  s[]=scc.split("");
    System.out.println(s.length);

    for( j=0;j<s.length;j++)
    {

        if(s[j]!="a" && s[j]!="i" && s[j]!="o" && s[j]!="u" &&s[j]!="e")
            Count++;
    }
    System.out.println(Count);
}}
```

`

Comment: `==` won't work on Strings. But you don't need to split, you can use `toCharArray`  or `charAt` (and `==` works fine on a `char`).

Comment: You can try this: `scc = scc.replaceAll("[aeiou]+", ""); 
System.out.printf("Length of string: %d", scc.length());`